# move_uploaded_files works with suPHP, but not DSO

Tags: php, suphp

i have a dedicated server with one site. i have DSO enabled. i have to have it enabled as suPHP is a serious resource hog. the load time between DSO and suPHP is night and day.

i have an issue with move_uploaded_files. under DSO PHP is running as a webserver process. the file's owner is always set to nobody and move_uploaded_files throws a permissions error. if i have suPHP enabled, then file's owner is set to the username and the move_uploaded_files works fine. anybody know how i can run with DSO enabled and have it so the file owner can be username?

thanks,
john

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. i had to reboot the server. can you believe that? all these hours running tests, checking logs, etc.